# Shifting data from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have been asked to build a report that looks at data from an IT service desk. When a user logs a ticket they log it under either "Main" or "Sub" - these are the parent categories. What complicates things for me is that these parent catagories have child categories with differing numbers of levels. The system was designed quite poorly so there isn't any columns called "Main" or "Sub" - just a bunch of columns for the different categories. Below is an example

```
ID       Cat1     Cat2      Cat3    Cat4
22       MV       Main       NULL    NULL
23       Backup   Sec        Test    Main
25       AV       SUB2       SUB     NULL
```

Each ticket always has less than 4 levels in the hierarchy, and the main category is always the last populated column in a row (on the left). Sometimes all 4 columns can be populated and sometimes it could just be 2. What I want to do is create some code that will put the Main Category in a column on the left, with all the other categories following it.

So the above would then look like the following

```
ID       MainCategory        Cat1      Cat2      Cat3
22       Main                MV         NULL      NULL
23       Main                Test       Sec       Backup
25       SUB                 SUB2       AV      NULL
```

Could someone help with this? I tried coalesce with no joy and I can't really get my head around how I could achieve this!

Appreciate any help
Jess

Comment: What happened to AV in the last row?

Comment: Fixed this sorry it was a mistake

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by determining the main category (using `coalesce()`) and then using `nullif()` to `null` out that value in the other columns:

```
select t.id, v.maincat,
       nullif(t.cat1, v.maincat) as cat1,
       nullif(t.cat2, v.maincat) as cat2,
       nullif(t.cat3, v.maincat) as cat3
from t cross apply
     (values (coalesce(t.cat4, t.cat3, t.cat2, t.cat1)) v(maincat);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4f10ac5220c447be169dc3cfbf64b925) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - I tried this but I still get nulls in the 2nd column where the next category should be (after main category)

Comment: @Jess8766 . . . There was a small typo in the `values()` clause.  The logic works.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

As long as Main/SUB exist exactly once per row:

```
select ID, Cat1 as MainCategory, Cat2 as Cat1, Cat3 as Cat2, Cat4 as Cat3
from tablename where Cat1 in ('Main', 'SUB')
UNION ALL
select ID, Cat2, Cat1, Cat3, Cat4
from tablename where Cat2 in ('Main', 'SUB')
UNION ALL
select ID, Cat3, Cat1, Cat2, Cat4
from tablename where Cat3 in ('Main', 'SUB')
UNION ALL
select ID, Cat4, Cat1, Cat2, Cat3
from tablename where Cat4 in ('Main', 'SUB')

-- To include rows without both Main and SUB, add

UNION ALL
select ID, Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4
from tablename
where Cat1 not in ('Main', 'SUB')
  and Cat2 not in ('Main', 'SUB')
  and Cat3 not in ('Main', 'SUB')
  and Cat4 not in ('Main', 'SUB')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the additional column or add a column to the existing table and then update the new column.

```
UPDATE #NewTable
SET main = 'Main'
where cat1 = 'Main' or cat2 = 'Main' or cat3 = 'Main' or cat4 = 'Main'

UPDATE #NewTable
SET main = 'Sub' 
where cat1 = 'SUB' or cat2 = 'SUB' or cat3 = 'SUB' or cat4 = 'SUB'

UPDATE #NewTable
SET cat1 = null
where cat1 in ('Main', 'SUB') 

UPDATE #NewTable
SET cat2 = null
where cat2 in ('Main', 'SUB') 

UPDATE #NewTable
SET cat3 = null
where cat3 in ('Main', 'SUB') 

UPDATE #NewTable
SET cat4 = null
where cat4 in ('Main', 'SUB')
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have the permissions to do this. Was hoping to just write code to give me an output instead of modifying/creating tables. Thanks